Sonar coverage exclusion not ignoring classes
Currently I have updated my application to springboot 3 and Java 21, unfortunately the configuration classes are not ignored anymore which affects the coverage percentage.
Build gradle:
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    jacoco
    id("org.openapi.generator") version "7.4.0"
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.2.4"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.0"
    id("org.sonarqube") version "3.3"
    id("info.solidsoft.pitest") version "1.7.4"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen") version "1.9.23"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.23"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.9.23"
    kotlin("kapt") version "1.9.23"
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.9.23"
}

pitest {
    setProperty("junit5PluginVersion", "0.12")
    setProperty("testPlugin", "junit5")
    setProperty("targetClasses", listOf("com.bff.*"))
    setProperty("outputFormats", listOf("HTML"))
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir("build/generated/src/main/java")
        }
    }
}

openApiGenerate {
    generatorName.set("spring")
    inputSpec.set("$rootDir/src/main/resources/openapi.yaml")
    outputDir.set("$buildDir/generated")
    packageName.set("com.bff.controller.openapi")
    apiPackage.set("com.bff.controller.openapi.api")
    modelPackage.set("com.bff.controller.openapi.model")
        skipOverwrite.set(false)

    configOptions.set(
        mapOf(
            Pair("interfaceOnly", "true"),
            Pair("skipDefaultInterface", "true"),
            Pair("identifierNamingConvention", "snake_case"),
            Pair(
                "additionalModelTypeAnnotations",
                "@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude(com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)"
            ),
            Pair("useJakartaEe", "true"),
            Pair("useSpringBoot3", "true")

        )
    )

}


group = "com.bff"
version = "1.1.0"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_21

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom(configurations.annotationProcessor.get())
    }
}

extra["log4j2.version"] = "2.15.0"
extra["springCloudVersion"] = "2023.0.1"
dependencies {
IMPLEMENTATIONS...................
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${property("springCloudVersion")}")
    }
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.11"
}

tasks.withType<JacocoReport> {
    classDirectories.setFrom(
        sourceSets.main.get().output.asFileTree.matching {
            exclude(
                "**/configuration/**",
                "**/data/**",
                "**/enum/**",
                "**/mapper/**",
                "**/openapi/**",
                "**/exception/**",
                "**/factory/**",
                "**/context/**",
                "**/Application.*"
            )
        }
    )
}
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property("sonar.java.coveragePlugin", "jacoco")
        property("sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPath", layout.buildDirectory.file("/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml").get())
        property("sonar.inclusions", "**/src/main/kotlin/**/*")
        property(
            "sonar.coverage.exclusions",
            "**/configuration/**," +
                    "**/data/**," +
                    "**/enum/**," +
                    "**/mapper/**," +
                    "**/openapi/**," +
                    "**/exception/**," +
                    "**/factory/**," +
                    "**/context/**," +
                    "**/util/**," +
                    "**/Application.*"
        )
    }
}

tasks.jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn(tasks.test)
    reports {
        xml.required.set(true)
        html.required.set(true)
    }
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "21"
    }
}

tasks.getByName<Jar>("jar") {
    enabled = false
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    finalizedBy(tasks.getByName("jacocoTestReport"))
}

tasks.register<Zip>("zip") {
    archiveFileName.set("${project.rootProject.name}-${project.rootProject.version}.zip")
    destinationDirectory.set(layout.buildDirectory.dir("${project.buildDir}/distributions"))
    from(layout.buildDirectory.dir("${project.buildDir}/libs")) {
        exclude("*-plain.jar")
    }
}

tasks.compileKotlin {
    dependsOn("openApiGenerate")
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "21"
}
tasks.compileTestKotlin {
    dependsOn("openApiGenerate")
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "21"
}

project.tasks.withType(KotlinCompile::class.java).configureEach {
    dependsOn("openApiGenerate")
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "21"
}

As you can see I added 'property("sonar.coverage.exclusions", "/configuration/," +...' but in the report

I tried to put the whole path but it doesn't work.
